# Laravel OrderBy relationship count without loading models (count)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an `episodes` table and an `episode_Listen` table, which is a One episode to Many listens
I want to get the 6 episodes with highest listens. I've tried every single solution like the following:

```php
$trending = Episode::where('active', true)
                            ->get()->sortBy(function($podcast) {
                                return $podcast->latestListens;
                            });
```

Or

```php
$trending = Episode::where('active', true)
                    ->withCount('listens')
                    ->orderBy('listens_count', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

Or

```php
$trending = Episode::join('episode_listens', function ($join) {
    $join->on('episode_listens.episode_id', '=', 'episodes.id');
})
->groupBy('episodes.id')
->orderBy('count', 'desc')
->select((['episodes.*', DB::raw('COUNT(episode_listens.podcast_id) as count')]))->paginate(6);
```

But the execution time always exceeds 6 seconds, because I've around 500k listens records in the database, and they'll go millions in a very short period of time.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if your tables are properly indexed. However - For this you need to read the entire `episode_listens` table. That can be slow. You might need to maintain a counter column in the `episodes` to improve the performance.

Comment: there will be slow if you counting or summing the data from database,
the alternative way to fix this you can use follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246532/mysql-sum-query-is-extremely-slow